# ggplot ribbon colour variation dependent on value with variable y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to graph two time series off sales for two items across a 12 month period (subset below). The sales of each item is influenced by the promotion condition of the other product, sometimes (due to seasonality) this causes a decrease in sales while other times it actually promotes sales. In order to represent this I have created two line graphs which are facet wrapped. In each facet we have one set of item sales(y = Sales), and its cross effect (y = cross_effect; dashed line) which shows the effect of the opposing promotion on sales, between these two lines I have a ribbon filling the gap in powderblue to demonstrate the magnitude. The ylim is allowed to vary with the data input.
The issues I am not sure how to fix:

1. Is it possible to make the colour of the ribbon and/or the cross-effect line vary i.e. green for increase and red for decrease?
2. How can I specify my Y sales to be rounded to 10s if max value is 100, 100s if max is under 1000... up to 100000s?

Thanks for taking the time to read my question! :smiley:

Here is some toy data and one of my attempts...

```
my_breaks <- function(x){seq(min(0), max(x), length.out = 5)}
my_labels <- function(x){round(x, digits = 0)}
Prop_change_df %>%
  mutate(cross_effect = as.integer(cross_effect))%>%
  mutate(cross_eff_gp = as.factor(if_else(cross_effect > Sales, "Lift", "Decline"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = day, group = Items)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Sales, ymax=cross_effect, fill = Sales - cross_effect > 0), fill = "powderblue")+
  geom_line(aes(y  = Sales, colour = interaction(Items, cross_eff_gp)), size = 0.25) +
  geom_line(aes(y  = cross_effect), size = 0.25, linetype="twodash", colour = "#F8766D") +
  facet_wrap(~ Items, scales = 'free', nrow = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = my_breaks, labels = my_labels) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("turquoise4","green1","turquoise4","darkgreen"))

    structure(list(day = structure(c(1546300800, 1547078400, 1554850800, 
    1554937200, 1555023600, 1555110000, 1555196400, 1555282800, 1555369200, 
    1555455600, 1555542000, 1555628400, 1547164800, 1555714800, 1555801200, 
    1555887600, 1555974000, 1556060400, 1556146800, 1556233200, 1556319600, 
    1556406000, 1556492400, 1547251200, 1556578800, 1556665200, 1556751600, 
    1556838000, 1556924400, 1557010800, 1557097200, 1557183600, 1557270000, 
    1557356400, 1547337600, 1557442800, 1557529200, 1557615600, 1557702000, 
    1557788400, 1557874800, 1557961200, 1558047600, 1558134000, 1558220400, 
    1547424000, 1558306800, 1558393200, 1558479600, 1558566000, 1558652400, 
    1558738800, 1558825200, 1558911600, 1558998000, 1559084400, 1547510400, 
    1559170800, 1559257200, 1559343600), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), rowname = c("1", "10", "100", "101", "102", "103", 
    "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "11", "110", "111", 
    "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", "119", "12", 
    "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", "128", 
    "129", "13", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", 
    "137", "138", "139", "14", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", 
    "145", "146", "147", "148", "149", "15", "150", "151", "152"), 
        Items = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("ITEMA", "ITEMB"), class = "factor"), 
        Sales = c(344L, 250L, 316L, 187L, 196L, 151L, 236L, 170L, 
        137L, 231L, 258L, 194L, 327L, 300L, 144L, 240L, 196L, 222L,
    292L, 215L, 241L, 210L, 156L, 408L, 151L, 137L, 168L, 172L, 
    203L, 186L, 197L, 148L, 154L, 139L, 363L, 136L, 183L, 177L, 
    130L, 141L, 132L, 144L, 143L, 152L, 165L, 402L, 128L, 133L, 
    163L, 113L, 164L, 171L, 162L, 116L, 117L, 128L, 432L, 107L, 
    125L, 187L), z_diff_HC = c(15.5644333787362, 1.87906641317019, 
    12.557755209854, 14.8812985333839, 17.5223825569917, 23.8360074736518, 
    18.7410953048883, 14.9583507793006, 13.9273511861036, -3.51818494122973, 
    12.1544583602306, 3.02440323681235, 3.82962965039171, 17.5478815812969, 
    3.3229377520704, 0.633981373873377, 9.27905096386199, 12.5799626114306, 
    14.2247591638052, 16.6487747981391, 15.8304549924645, 9.15979751528926, 
    15.0129291111416, -0.688334784614703, -7.63226366995004, 
    0.428951331549642, 10.2702773598704, 36.1219319585148, 15.4142833246758, 
    4.88470834307489, 21.2490429809954, -7.33361550396995, -4.29869918645501, 
    18.9489364038734, -1.76460720804452, -1.35823311958288, 34.6935883900468, 
    1.48949451885331, -0.787584852115686, -4.934382699854, 29.0731805864111, 
    -2.26200238484375, 4.65925660604302, 4.57357539667069, 13.5774688780233, 
    -7.43056606661547, 6.80825163894218, 26.2460480670466, -0.0345819873156576, 
    -4.12627881544668, 21.9890241216193, 8.85020652256215, -4.58203685844702, 
    -1.56753295765628, 6.87606203426416, -1.24701222724131, -5.49773520072737, 
    26.6408805552948, 13.7954350138116, 2.38997658321286), z_diff_LC = c(13.3437666668954, 
    14.5236741281306, 10.7951593816903, 4.84956568132256, 7.45825970577198, 
    21.9209205048645, 13.771397911861, 7.45865297041878, 6.46080539304303, 
    5.14672039650974, 12.5316920559886, 15.2040992604187, 12.6541200645773, 
    14.2950716064143, 10.5446098231127, 6.43989960683895, 16.4096578863693, 
    16.4101967481371, 16.0975590010918, 12.6720845665324, 16.1643139814777, 
    11.6413490880193, 2.83465891620418, 10.8460318787892, 9.15035156783542, 
    10.2708678061698, 14.1911274394713, 23.0683580892434, 16.8380931420443, 
    4.8403754007098, 7.18799162588475, 6.36638381655323, 8.24158256116018, 
    11.3007628036994, 12.9255831702492, 6.41222412825569, 19.7883919842208, 
    13.3191292882506, 12.7806778770094, 4.86388566858485, 14.6793005237244, 
    2.42776728708029, 7.3976730645803, 12.0699413784232, 6.69843620821456, 
    12.048529261754, -0.949761782343618, 24.7048534238846, 7.06724785291648, 
    1.66908179491139, -0.863601498137782, 11.8756265308355, 11.5238370520726, 
    4.17572476604349, 10.6038524757556, 11.5103217175066, 11.4243857521004, 
    1.35708802651482, 1.5516675954511, 13.6221661122224), cross_effect = c(389.90255733412, 
    286.309185320327, 350.112703646141, 196.068687824073, 210.618189023313, 
    184.100589962345, 268.500499071992, 182.679710049712, 145.851303388469, 
    242.888924115937, 290.331765504451, 223.495952565212, 368.378972611168, 
    342.885214819243, 159.184238145282, 255.455759056413, 228.162929457284, 
    258.430636780864, 339.004872283188, 242.244981818045, 279.955996695361, 
    234.44683308484, 160.422067909279, 452.25181006546, 164.817030867431, 
    151.071088894453, 191.841094098312, 211.677575913499, 237.18132907835, 
    195.00309824532, 211.160343502993, 157.422248048499, 166.692037144187, 
    154.708060297142, 409.919866908005, 144.720624814428, 219.212757331124, 
    200.574858840204, 146.614881240112, 147.858078792705, 151.376676691316, 
    147.495984893396, 153.57867248235, 170.346310895203, 176.052419743554, 
    450.435087632251, 126.7843049186, 165.857455053767, 174.519614000254, 
    114.88606242825, 162.583693543054, 191.307321367729, 180.668616024358, 
    120.84384072861, 129.406507396634, 142.733211798408, 481.353346449074, 
    108.452084188371, 126.939584494314, 212.473450629856)), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), key = structure(list(rowname = c("1", "10", "100", "101", 
"102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "11", 
"110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", 
"119", "12", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", 
"127", "128", "129", "13", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", 
"135", "136", "137", "138", "139", "14", "140", "141", "142", 
"143", "144", "145", "146", "147", "148", "149", "15", "150", 
"151", "152"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
    19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
    31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 
    43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
    55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 60L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), index = structure("day", ordered = TRUE), index2 = "day", interval = structure(list(
    year = 0, quarter = 0, month = 0, week = 0, day = 0, hour = 1, 
    minute = 0, second = 0, millisecond = 0, microsecond = 0, 
    nanosecond = 0, unit = 0), .regular = TRUE, class = c("interval", 
"vctrs_rcrd", "vctrs_vctr")), class = c("tbl_ts", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example data doesn't seem to involve any crossing of one line over the other, so it is difficult to see how it could be used to demonstrate a changing of the ribbon color according to which line was higher.

I have therefore produced a simple example data set:

```r
set.seed(8)

df  <- data.frame(day = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), by = "day", length = 100),
                  positive = cumsum(rnorm(100)),
                  negative = cumsum(rnorm(100)))

head(df)
#>          day    positive   negative
#> 1 2019-01-01 -0.08458607  0.2968513
#> 2 2019-01-02  0.75581405 -1.6037223
#> 3 2019-01-03  0.29233128 -3.2510879
#> 4 2019-01-04 -0.25850372 -5.0294934
#> 5 2019-01-05  0.47753671 -4.9945500
#> 6 2019-01-06  0.36965531 -5.4890964
```

An individual ribbon cannot change its aesthetic along its length, so if you want multiple different regions colored differently, you will need to group them individually. For a line that crosses several times, we can do it like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(effect = factor(cumsum(abs(c(0, diff(positive > negative)))))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(day, positive)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = "positive"), size = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = negative, color = "negative"), size = 1) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(fill = effect, ymin = negative, ymax = positive), 
              color = NA, alpha = 0.1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "forestgreen"), name = "") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rep(c("red", "forestgreen"), 20), 
                    guide = guide_none()) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I haven't looked at this for ages, but this an excellent answer. Thank you for this, sorry its been two years!